# Mousemove event after Onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have the [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384483/mousemove-event-updating-only-once-after-mousedown) but I'm using pure js. By my understanding after I clicked on the div it should start print 'Mousemove event has occurred' into the console every time I move the cursor over the div but actually it happens only once when I click the div which is weird as well because click is not a mosemove. Can you please help me to understand this behavior?

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid black 1px" onclick="handleClick(event)"></div>
  <script>
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    function handleClick(event){
      div.addEventListener('onmousemove', handleMove(event));
    }

    function handleMove(event){
      console.log('Mousemove event has occurred');
    }
  </script>
```

Looks like it ignores this part `div.addEventListener('onmousemove', handleMove(event));` and executes `handleMove(event);` instead:

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid black 1px" onclick="handleClick(event)"></div>
  <script>
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    function handleClick(event){
      handleMove(event);
    }

    function handleMove(event){
      console.log('Mousemove event has occurred');
    }
</script>
```

Update: I was thinking to pass `handleMove` without `()` but got confused by Atom IDE (due to pale highlight), [so do not let Atom confuse you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Xxs.png)

Comment: try to change `div.addEventListener('onmousemove', handleMove(event)); to div.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);` as seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_addeventlistener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like it ignores this part div.addEventListener('onmousemove', handleMove(event)); and executes handleMove(event); instead:

Yes, because it is what you wrote ;)

```
div.addEventListener('onmousemove', handleMove(event));
```

The above executes the `handleMove` function passing it the `event`.

Compare it to actually just creating an event handler (no parenthesis after `handleMove`):

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid black 1px" onclick="handleClick(event)"></div>
<script>
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    function handleClick(event){
      console.log(`handleClick`);
      div.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
    }

    function handleMove(event){
      console.log('Mousemove event has occurred');
    }
</script>
```

**Also: the event is [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) not [`onmousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousemove).**

Comment: Thank you @Sébastien for a quick and helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

the event listener should be "mousemove" and not "onmousemove".
something like this:

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid black 1px" onclick="handleClick(event)"></div>
  <script>
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    function handleClick(event){
      div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) { handleMove(event) });
    }

    function handleMove(event){
      console.log('Mousemove event has occurred');
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the syntax of addEventListener which is `document.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture)` here for parameter `event` clearly mention that([here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_document_addeventlistener.asp))

> Required. A String that specifies the name of the event.
>
> **Note:** Do not use the "on" prefix. For example, use "click" instead of "onclick".

So replace 'onmousemove' to 'mousemove'

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid black 1px" onclick="handleClick(event)"></div>
  <script>
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    
    function handleClick(event){
      div.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
    }

    function handleMove(event){
      console.log('Mousemove event has occurred');
    }
  </script>
```